# Multiple VS Code instances and system environment variables

Tags: visual-studio-code

I often have multiple instances of VS Code open on windows during extension development and testing and have noticed that the system environment variables available via process.env() seem to be "locked" to what the "first instance" sees.  For example:

1. Start VS Code, and open a folder
2. Open command prompt
3. set MYVARIABLE=something
4. start another VS Code from here using "code ."
5. Variable MYVARIABLE not available via process.env()
6. Close all instances of VS Code
7. start VS Code from command prompt using "code ."
8. MYVARIABLE is available

Just wondering if anyone knows if this is the expected behavior.

Comment: It's been an open issue for a while: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/47816